# When creating a circle sector in css, a slim line is visible in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css

I am a novice when it comes to css and am creating a custom audio player using a mixture of css and jquery. The progress bar of this audio player is a ring, which uses circle sectors to display progress. The sector is created using linear-gradient, like so:

```
background-image:
    linear-gradient(-75deg, black 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
```

In firefox this works perfectly, but in both chrome and ie, a very slim white line is visible on the outside of half of the circle, presumably where part of the linear-gradient is supposed to cover.

I have created a jsfiddle that displays the issue, https://jsfiddle.net/9dagsrzz/

Is there something that I am doing wrong that causes this, or is there a fix I can apply that removes this line?

Thank you for your time.

Edit - it has been over a month and I thought I would update and say that I have still not been able to find a complete solution to this problem. The best way of dealing with the issue is to include a covering border, as suggested by Pustur below.

Comment: Not really a solution but you could add a `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black` to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Samiskeen,

I'm no CSS expert either but I do know that each browser has its required prefixes when dealing with gradients:

```
-moz- is for Mozilla Firefox
-webkit- is for Apple Safari, Google Chrome, and also for ios and Android
-o- is for Opera
-ms- is for Microsoft IE and presumably Edge
```

You can have all of these present on their own line and the browser will pick the correct one.

Example:

```
background-image:

-moz-linear-gradient(-75deg, black 50%, transparent 50%),
-moz-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
-webkit-linear-gradient(-75deg, black 50%, transparent 50%),
-webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
-o-linear-gradient(-75deg, black 50%, transparent 50%),
-o-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
-ms-linear-gradient(-75deg, black 50%, transparent 50%),
-ms-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
```

The website http://caniuse.com lists the major CSS rules, attributes and whether browser specific versions are required.(Nixon, p. 439).

Play around with the prefixes, they should help correct your problem.

Good Luck.
Jim

Comment: I don't think it's a prefix issue or the gradients wouldn't show at all. They're mostly not needed anymore.

Comment: I have tried this and as the above comment says, this isn't a prefix issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a definitive solution or the best, but it seems to work fine at least on chrome.

HTML:

```
<!-- divs instead of spans -->
<div id="container">
  <div id="position_indicator"></div>
  <div id="inside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

#inside {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#position_indicator {
  border: 1px solid black; /* Fix the border issue! */
  margin-left: -1px; /* Compensate for the new border */
  margin-top: -1px; /* Compensate for the new border */

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ke2u2jj/2/)

Comment: Hi there, you need a 2px border to cover it completely, which works fine in chrome, but unfortunately doesn't work at all in ie.